# Facebook integration in xcode 4.5 with ios6?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-login

I need to integrate Facebook login page in my app.i.e I m providing user various login options like he can login with my website account or facebook account and continue the activities with in our app thats it.I dont want him to perform any other activities with facebook.He can just login.

So I have through some of the tutorials which say to drag and drop FBConnect and write some code.But when I drag and drop FBConnect Im getting errors when I complile project saying FBConnect/FBSession.h not found etc .

And sometimes Facebook tutorials say to use Appkey and AppSecret when using FBConnect.But sometimes they dont use, when importing FacebookSDK.framework

I couldnot understand how could I proceed further.
Should I use FBConnect ?Is AppKey neccessary?**I just want to give option to user that he can login through Facebook also in my app**

Please guide me in this aspect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes even for giving user a option to login with facebook  , you need to integrate the facebook sdk and the app id is required.
Since you are using xcode 4.5 then you have to use facebook sdk 3.1 not 3.0.(it will give errors).
See the developers.facebook.com, they have provided all the details you want.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/

http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

First you need to set up environment for your app:-

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Then implement the login feature:-

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

I hope this might helps you.

Comment: But in the links u provided I dont find usage of App key anywhere.Is it useful?

Comment: see in this link:- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ there is mention how to create a app  id. When you have an app id you need to replace in the sdk.